# Can I call a socket.io server from a go client?

Tags: node.js, go, socket.io

I have a socket.io server with nodejs. I currently have a web page on the same server acting as a client.

I wanted add a command line tool (preferably in golang) to listen to the same server.

Is it something that is supported? I tried to look around but maybe I don't know how to exactly look for this information.

I saw [this](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io) but it looks like a re-implementation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io/issues/192) the go-socket-io project is abandoned because the sole developer lost interest. Perhaps you can search for a better alternative on pkg.go.dev. There's [this](https://github.com/abelwei/socket.io.client) one for example.

Comment: for a websocket client, you can use https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/websocket

Comment: @whitespace I was looking for something specific for socket.io but I guess it's not something out there. I saw there is an office JVM implementation. I will do the console program in Java